# Ejecutar una funcion cada determinado tiempo

Tags: python, python-2.7

Quiero hacer que se ejecute una funcion cada hora la funcion que quiero ejecutar cada hora se llama `enviarDatos()`

```
def ejecutaScript():
    enviarDatos()
    print 'Ejecutando script...'
    time.sleep(15)
    while True:
        ejecutaScript()
```

Tengo esto pero no me funciona, inicialmente puse 15 segundos para hacer la prueba, agradeceria una ayuda

Answer (score 1):

El `time.sleep(15)` tendría que ir dentro del while, y el while, fuera de la función para no tener problemas de llamadas dentro de llamadas

```
def ejecutaScript():
    enviarDatos()
    print 'Ejecutando script...'

while True:
    ejecutaScript()
    time.sleep(15)
```

Evidentemente, tienes que definir la función `enviarDatos()` en algún lugar, pero imagino que eso lo tienes por ahí.

Lo que tienes ahora, creo que debería funcionar (siempre y cuando se haga una llamada a `ejecutaScript()` en algún lado, pero te puede dar problemas de recurrencia. Porque no paras de llamar a la misma función una y otra vez por toda la eternidad (`while True`), sin nunca terminar la función. Hay un límite al número de veces que puedes llamar a una función desde otra sin finalizarla. Al final te daría un error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: La pregunta definitivamente tiene recursión infinita.